# How do I get a list of open tasks for a single user using the Active Collab 5 API?

Tags: php, web-services, sdk, activecollab

The self hosted Active Collab 5 has the following API documentation:
https://developers.activecollab.com/api-documentation/index.html

The problem is, there is not a clear way to pull a list of open tasks (across all projects) for a single user.

This will be similar to the tasks listed on this page on the installation: http://{AC5-selfhostedURL}/my-work

We are using the `AssignmentFilters` as listed here: https://developers.activecollab.com/api-documentation/v1/reports-and-filters/assignments-filter.html -- And we are calling the API as listed on the sample below:

```
$reportsTaskArr = $client2->get('reports/run?type=AssignmentFilter&include_subtasks='.false)->getJson();
```

It seems there are parameters not documented for the filters.

Comment: Please post the relevant code for review by the community.

Comment: ok... Just added more info

Comment: If you find the answer below useful, and gets the job done for the use case that you need to cover, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to get a list of open assignments for a user is to `GET` this resource:

`/users/:user_id/tasks`

That response is used on My Work page for logged in user, as well as for open task listings on user's profile page in the People section.